# Draw and move shapes across canvas with an interval

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to make my own "Flappy Bird" clone in my spare time, but I'm having trouble getting the "pipes" to draw and scroll at a set interval. I'm able to draw one set and move it, but having it repeatedly draw and move it in an interval is eluding me.

Any insight as to what I need to do would be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //global vars   
    var world = document.getElementById('gameWorld');
    var startScreen = document.getElementById('startScreen');
    var context = world.getContext('2d');

    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
    })()


    //bord constructor  
    function bordBuilder(){
        this.radius = 10;
        this.x = world.width / 2;
        this.y = world.height / 2;
        this.vy = -20;
        this.gravity = 0.8;
    }

    function pipesBuilder(){
        this.width = 50;
        this.x = world.width;

    }
    // draw the Bord on the stage
    function drawBord(bord, context){
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(bord.x, bord.y, bord.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        context.fillStyle = 'blue';
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        context.strokeStyle = 'navyblue';
        context.stroke();
    }

    //function to check whether or not the bord is hitting the top or bottom of the stage
    function fallingBord(bord){
        bord.y += bord.gravity;
        if(bord.y < 0 + bord.radius){
            bord.y = bord.radius;
        }else if(bord.y + bord.radius > world.height){
            bord.y = world.height - bord.radius;
        }
    }

    //animation function always running
    function startAnimation(bord, context, pipes){
        context.clearRect(0, 0, world.width, world.height);
        drawBord(bord, context);
        fallingBord(bord);
        setInterval(function(){ 
            drawPipes(pipes, context);
        }, 3000);

        movePipes(pipes);
        requestAnimFrame(function(){
            startAnimation(bord, context, pipes);
        });
    }

    //make the bird fly higher every click
    function flyHigher(bord){
        console.log('higher');
        bord.y += bord.vy;
    }

    //pipe function/hitboxes
    function drawPipes(pipes, context){
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(pipes.x, world.height-50, pipes.width,50);
        context.fillStyle = 'green';
        context.fill();

        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(pipes.x, 0, pipes.width, 50);
        context.fillStyle = 'green';
        context.fill();
    }

    //function to move the pipes from the left to right
    function movePipes(pipes){
        pipes.x -= 1;
    }


    var pipes = new pipesBuilder();
    var bord = new bordBuilder();

    //add the fly event listener to the stage
    world.addEventListener("click", function(){
        flyHigher(bord);
    }, false);
    startScreen.addEventListener("click", function(){
        startScreen.style.display = 'none';
        startAnimation(bord, context, pipes);
    }, false);
});
```

```css
#gameWorld{
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#startScreen{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
#startScreen h1{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="startScreen"><h1>START</h1></div>
<canvas id="gameWorld"></canvas>
```

Comment: Can you describe what is actually happening and what you expect to happen; try to narrow down the problem to at least part of your code

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API
look here you will find the answere out ^^

Comment: @JamesThorpe Apologies for not saying that. What's happening is the objects (rectangles) are not drawn on the screen, yet when I call the "movePipe" function, they do end up moving in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were simply missing a notion of multiple pipes. I've modified your code, so `pipes` is now an array of pipes and their draw/move function work with each individual pipe. I've also added a `newPipe` function that gets called in the interval (which I've moved out of the render loop).

Since pipes pile up - I added a delete function which removes those pipes that pass the left canvas edge.

Here we go:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //global vars   
    var world = document.getElementById('gameWorld');
    var startScreen = document.getElementById('startScreen');
    var context = world.getContext('2d');

    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
    })()


    //bord constructor  
    function bordBuilder(){
        this.radius = 10;
        this.x = world.width / 2;
        this.y = world.height / 2;
        this.vy = -20;
        this.gravity = 0.8;
    }

    function pipesBuilder(){
        this.width = 50;
        this.x = world.width;

    }
    // draw the Bord on the stage
    function drawBord(bord, context){
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(bord.x, bord.y, bord.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        context.fillStyle = 'blue';
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        context.strokeStyle = 'navyblue';
        context.stroke();
    }

    //function to check whether or not the bord is hitting the top or bottom of the stage
    function fallingBord(bord){
        bord.y += bord.gravity;
        if(bord.y < 0 + bord.radius){
            bord.y = bord.radius;
        }else if(bord.y + bord.radius > world.height){
            bord.y = world.height - bord.radius;
        }
    }

    //animation function always running
    function startAnimation(bord, context, pipes){
        context.clearRect(0, 0, world.width, world.height);
        drawBord(bord, context);
        fallingBord(bord);
        
        drawPipes(pipes, context);
        movePipes(pipes);
        requestAnimFrame(function(){
            startAnimation(bord, context, pipes);
        });
    }

    //make the bird fly higher every click
    function flyHigher(bord){
        console.log('higher');
        bord.y += bord.vy;
    }

    //pipe function/hitboxes
    function drawPipes(pipes, context){
      for(var i = 0; i < pipes.length; i++){
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(pipes[i].x, world.height-50, pipes[i].width,50);
        context.fillStyle = 'green';
        context.fill();

        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(pipes[i].x, 0, pipes[i].width, 50);
        context.fillStyle = 'green';
        context.fill();
      }
    }

    //function to move the pipes from the left to right
    function movePipes(pipes){
      for(var i = 0; i < pipes.length; i++){
        pipes[i].x -= 1;
        if (i == 0 && pipes[i].x < -pipes[i].width) {
          console.log('deleting pipe');
          pipes.splice(i, 1);
          }
        }
    }
  
  function newPipe(pipes){
    pipes.push(new pipesBuilder());
    }


    var pipes = [new pipesBuilder()];
    var bord = new bordBuilder();

    //add the fly event listener to the stage
    world.addEventListener("click", function(){
        flyHigher(bord);
      drawPipes(pipes, context);
    }, false);
    startScreen.addEventListener("click", function(){
        startScreen.style.display = 'none';
        startAnimation(bord, context, pipes);
        setInterval(function(){ 
          console.log('new pipe', pipes);
            newPipe(pipes);
        }, 3000);
    }, false);
});
```

```css
#gameWorld{
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#startScreen{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
#startScreen h1{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="startScreen"><h1>START</h1></div>
<canvas id="gameWorld"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ah this is what I expected to happen! Thanks for the input, I'm not sure I would have thought about using an array. Cheers @Shomz

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, without an array (or some other way of grouping them), you'd be able to have only one pipe on screen at any given moment.